# Relocating the PVC from behind dishwasher

Tags: plumbing, pipe, dishwasher, pvc

I want to replace a 12 year old dishwasher with a new KitchenAid model. The hot and cold PVC pipes from under kitchen sink are blocking a full install. These pipes are not flush against the wall or low enough to sit in the recessed space behind dishwasher.

The dishwasher hoses have been connected and the unit is operational.  However, I cannot mount it to the counter since I've lost 4-5 inches of space behind the dishwasher due to these two pipes. A plumber quoted $250 after seeing these photos on line, but not in person. He said I was far from him so he wasn't coming all the way out just to give a quote. Not cool, so I told him I would shop around.

I've made other PVC pipe repairs and feel humbly confident I could reroute these pipes myself in one of two ways after the PVC enters this space using elbow joints:

1. run PVC lower along floor and drywall
2. or deeper and flush with the wall

Will a plumber be required or is this a DYI project?

[image: Source of PVC]
[image: PVC behind Dishwasher]

Comment: Would! That was a pretty bad place to put pipes in a dishwasher space.

Comment: I bought the house built in 1994 with polybutylene plumbing and had all of it removed. There were a few decisions made based sold on laziness by the contractor that I would have never allowed if I had known the reprocussions at that time. I'm paying for their sloppiness now.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, a handy DIY person could do the re-routing of those hot and cold water line connections. You would have to deal with shutting off the water supply, cutting out all the old stuff and then re-plumbing in with new piping and fittings. Hopefully you get all the parts that you would need in one initial trip to the big box store. Do be aware as you get ready to re-route the pipes as close to the wall and as low as possible you may be faced with that electrical box back there being in the way.

After all that the quote really does not sound so bad considering the nature of today's prices for things. But it is totally doable if you have the gumption and determination to see it through. It may even be the occasion to acquire some new tools!!

Comment: +1 agree, except for the "big box" comment. OP would be much better off, and way more likely to do a "one trip" job, if they go to a good local plumbing shop or good established mom and pop hardware store.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a DIY project, PVC is easy to work with. Only thing you really need to watch out for is to make sure the new piping you install is CPVC. Neither Schedule 40 nor Schedule 80 PVC (the other most common kinds) are not legal for install inside the house in most jurisdictions. CPVC is also the only kind of PVC rated for hot water.

That said, depending on your area 250 for even a simple reworking of your piping isn't bad at all for a licensed, insured plumber.